# Fancy String Formatting

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to format a table to look something like this:

```
0 Banana    1 Apple         2 Orange
3 Pear      4 Grape         5 Coconut
6 Test1     7 Test2         8 Test3
9 Test4     10 TestTest5    11 TestTest6
```

The minimum number of spaces between the items should be 4. From 0 Banana to 1 Apple, and 10 TestTest5 and 11 TestTest6. Aligned to the left.

I'm trying using this string formatation...

```
i = 0
line = ""
whole = ""
for n,m in enumerate(grid):
    if i <3:
        line += "%s %-13s" % (n, m)
    else:
        whole += "%s\n"%line
        line = "%s %-13s" % (n, m)
        i = 0
    i += 1
whole += "%s\n" % line
whole = whole.replace("'", "")
whole = whole.replace('"', "")

print whole
```

but the result isn't quite the same

```
0 Banana       1 Apple        2 Orange       
3 Pear         4 Grape        5 Coconut      
6 Test1        7 Test2        8 Test3        
9 Test4        10 TestTest5    11 TestTest6
```

How can I achieve this? I guess I need some way to change the %-13s depending on the length of the above/bellow rows.

Comment: Why not format the numbers to use *two* positions? E.g. `' 0 Banana'` and `'10 TestTest5'` to have the numbers line up.

Comment: @Christian: Presumably a sequence of strings. Doesn't matter all that much, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this (if you want 4 blanks between the columns, depending on the longest element of each column):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

def printGrid (it, columns):
    items = ['{} {}'.format (idx, item) for idx, item in enumerate (it) ]
    maxWidths = [max (len (item) for item in items [col::columns] ) for col in range (columns) ]
    padded = [item + ' ' * (4 + maxWidths [idx % columns] - len (item) ) for idx, item in enumerate (items) ]
    while True:
        if not padded: break
        items = padded [:columns]
        padded = padded [columns:]
        print (' '.join (items) )

data = 'Banana,Apple,Orange,Pear,Grape,Coconut,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,TestTest5,TestTest6,Test7'.split (',')
printGrid (data, 3)
```

Or using builtin formats:

```
def printGrid (it, columns):
    items = ['{} {}'.format (idx, item) for idx, item in enumerate (it) ]
    maxWidths = [max (4 + len (item) for item in items [col::columns] ) for col in range (columns) ]
    formatStr = ''.join ('{{:<{}}}'.format (width) for width in maxWidths)
    while True:
        if not items: break
        line = items [:columns]
        items = items [columns:]
        while len (line) < columns: line.append ('')
        print (formatStr.format (*line) )
```

---

Explanation:

`items` builds the list of items, formatted as index + space + item

`maxWidth` calculates the maximum width for each column

(1st snippet:) `padded` pads each item according to its column

(2nd snippet:) `formatStr` does what you asked for: "change the %-13s depending on the length of the above/bellow rows"

(2nd snippet:) `while len...`: Pads the line, so the formatStr gets the right number of arguments

The rest is printing.

Comment: This works flawless, might explain? I can barely understand it.

Comment: @f.rodrigues I will add an explanation.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Done. Any questions, just shoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the number and string first before formatting:

```
for n, m in enumerate(grid):
    if not n or n % 3:
        line += "%-15s" % (str(n) + ' ' + m)
    else:
        whole += "%s\n" % line
        line = "%-15s" % (str(n) + ' ' + m)
```

which produces:

```
0 Banana       1 Apple        2 Orange       
3 Pear         4 Grape        5 Coconut      
6 Test1        7 Test2        8 Test3        
9 Test4        10 TestTest5   11 TestTest6
```

or you could format your numbers to *two* positions, right-aligned:

```
for n, m in enumerate(grid):
    if not n or n % 3:
        line += "%2d %-12s" % (n, m)
    else:
        whole += "%s\n" % line
        line = "%2d %-12s" % (n, m)
```

which produces:

```
 0 Banana       1 Apple        2 Orange      
 3 Pear         4 Grape        5 Coconut     
 6 Test1        7 Test2        8 Test3       
 9 Test4       10 TestTest5   11 TestTest6
```

Comment: These are no doubt neat tables, but this doesn't answer the question about fixed number of spaces between columns.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: The question is a little vague on that point.. But since you got the accept mark, your interpretation was clearly closer to the mark. :-)